# JDCB error using xPages Extension Library JDBC Query

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm trying to set up s prototype for accessing Oracle data in an xPage using the JDBC Query in the Extension Library. I'm getting the following errors:

> Error while reading the relational data Error while loading connection
>   cos11p Error loading JDBC driver class
>   com.oracle.jdbc.driver_1.0.0.20141104-1319. If running the server,
>   check that an OSGi plugin wrapper for the corresponding JDBC driver is
>   available on the server, or that the corresponding package is
>   available in the WEB-INF/lib directory. If running the studio, check
>   that the corresponding package is available in your client library.
>   java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver
>   com.oracle.jdbc.driver_1.0.0.20141104-1319 Cannot create JDBC driver
>   com.oracle.jdbc.driver_1.0.0.20141104-1319
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class
>   com.oracle.jdbc.driver_1.0.0.20141104-1319 in NSF Cannot find class
>   com.oracle.jdbc.driver_1.0.0.20141104-1319 in NSF
>   com.oracle.jdbc.driver_1.0.0.20141104-1319

Here is what I have done so far to set this up:
1. Installed latest version of extension library on the server
2. Installed JDBC driver on the server using the Open NTF wizard
3. created cos11p.jdbc connection file located in WebContent\WEB-INF\JDBC

```
<jdbc>
<driver>com.oracle.jdbc.driver_1.0.0.20141104-1319</driver>
<url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@//sodb2p.malt-o-meal.com:1521/cos11p</url>
<user>username</user>
<password>password</password>
</jdbc>
```

4. Created xpage with view panel using JDBC Query pointing to jdcb connection
5. Xpage application properties have relational and extlib libraries checked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That "JDBC driver class" from the error looks wrong. I believe it should be "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver". In the JDBC driver plugin wizard, the "class" field should use that String I've quoted, which references a class within the JDBC driver you've downloaded (not the filename of the driver itself). It's a key part of getting the generated OSGi plugin to work correctly.

And in the JDBC file, you would then use the same class name in the "driver" parameter. I don't think there should be a date stamp in that parameter at all

Comment: Bingo! I had initially had the driver parameter as "com.oracle.jdbc.driver" and then matched it with the actual driver name.  Needs to be "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" as you suggested.  Thanks!

Comment: Great. Even with the wizard, it can be a bit tricky to get perfectly right. Glad it worked

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that the OSGi driver was loaded properly? Try

```
tell http osgi ss oracle
```

to check

Comment: I did do that.   It says "resolved" with the driver name I showed in my jdbc file.